# Views exposed date filter range format

Tags: views, 8, datetime

I have a view with an exposed filter for a date range. I use jquery ui datepicker to select dates. It works good and I can select dates in spanish format (dd/mm/yyyy). But when I apply the filter, It understands that the format is mm/dd/yyyy and It doesn't work good. In the worst case, if the day is greater than 12, It throws an error due to invalid date because It understands that the first number is the month.
How could I fix this issue?

Comment: There may be some help here, https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/263311/how-do-i-change-date-format-in-view-exposed-date-filter

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've done it, but I have found another problem with date range.  It works only if I put min and max date.

Comment: That makes sense, that's what the module is made for.