# How to Restrict views Date popup to only year/month

Tags: 8, datetime

I want to have views exposed filter on node `created` field with popup.
I've installed date_popup, the popup appears but I'm looking for a way to restrict it to only year and month.

[image]

I tried the following solutions but no success.

```
function HOOK_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  if( $form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-news-page-1') {
    $form['created']['#date_format'] = 'm-Y';
    $form['created']['#date_date_format'] = 'm-Y';
    $form['created']['value']['#date_format'] = 'm-Y';
    $form['created']['value']['#date_date_format'] = 'm-Y';
    $form['date_needed'] = [
      '#type' => 'date',
      '#title' => 'test',
      '#date_date_format' => 'm/Y',
      '#date_format' => 'm/Y',
    ];
  }
  return $form;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is a way yet to adjust date granularity for an exposed filter. However, there is [a patch](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2868014) to introduce it.

Comment: @sonfd thank you for your attention. I'll try it. but waiting for other answers.

Comment: did you try '#datepicker_options' => array(
    'dateFormat' => date_popup_format_to_popup('m-Y'),
    ), ?

Comment: Have you seen this post, https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/263311/how-do-i-change-date-format-in-view-exposed-date-filter

Comment: Confused by your screenshots.  The first looks like a Javascript popup (from the date_popup module?).  The second looks like the native Chrome date picker.  If you do `<input type="date">` then you will always get the native date picker.  You need to do `<input type="text">` if you want to override this behavior.   But, I am not familiar with the date_popup to know how to integrate it with Form API.

Comment: @mpdonadio thanks for your attention. the first screenshot is the design that we want to have. the second one is my first try result.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a external library to do that. Something like [jQuery UI Month Picker Plugin](https://kidsysco.github.io/jquery-ui-month-picker/) and you'll probably will need to use a `textfield` rather than `date`.

OR

Use the [Month Year](https://www.drupal.org/project/month_year) module

> This module provides a month year field type.