# How to change date format in an ajax View's exposed Date filter that uses BEF?

Tags: views, 8

I have a view with Ajax option enabled and using some date filters with **better exposed filters** (latest version). What i'm trying to do is to change the default date format of a date filter from mm/dd/yy to dd/mm/yy.

I tried to implement [this solution](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/265888/96466). The format changes and the popup works fine, but the problem occurs when applying the filters, where it seems that the date filter value does not validate.

Any suggestions on how to change the date format of a BEF filter in an Ajax view?